# Hangman-Timer speed increasing when creating a new object (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, function, timer

Currently programming Hangman and I have the following problem:

When I create a new HangmanController (choosing a new word, ...) the timer works fine, the only thing is, when I create one more HangmanController, the speed is 2x faster, when I create one more HangmanController 3x, etc.
I create a HangmanController only when

Where's the problem? Or how can I make the timer better?

//Here's where I create a new HangmanController. This happens when the user changes the difficulty (pressing a button in the HTML)

```
function inithm(difficulty) {
    hm = new HangmanController();
    hm.hmModel.reset(hm.displayedWord.word, false, difficulty);
    UsedLetters();
};
```

//Constructor

```
HangmanController = function() {
    this.hmModel = new HangmanModel();
    //this.hmView = new HangmanView(document.getElementById('hm_view'));
    this.displayedWord = new DisplayedWord();
    this.userGuessField = document.getElementById('guessfield');
    this.userGuessField.focus();
    this.guessbutton = document.getElementById('guessbutton');
    this.guessbutton.disabled = false;
    /*this.updateTime = function(stopwatch) {
        var e = stopwatch.getElapsed();
        document.getElementById('stopwatch').innerHTML = e.hours * 60 + e.minutes + ' mins' + e.seconds + ' secs';
    };*/
    this.stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
};
```

//Timer, it is only called here, nowhere else (at setInterval)

```
Stopwatch = function() {
    this.sek = 0;
    setInterval(function() {timer();}, 1000);
};

function timer() {
    document.getElementById('stopwatch').innerHTML = this.hm.stopwatch.sek;
        this.hm.stopwatch.sek++;
}

Stopwatch.prototype.stop = function() {
    document.getElementById('stopwatch').innerHTML = 0;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating several instances of `Stopwatch` with each `HangmanController`, and everyone of them is calling timer() every second, which results in your #stopwatch element beeing increased more often than just once a second ;-)

**edit:** You should either dispose of the old `HangmanController` (especially the Stopwatch functionality) before creating a new one, or instead only create one instance of `HangmanController`, and make a method for restarting, or difficulty changes, etc..

Comment: Hmm how do I dispose the old HangmanController? I do not really understand that.

Comment: Easiest (but not cleanest) way in your case would be to first make hm global (e.g. right before the inithm() function put: "var hm = null;") and then as first line in inithm() right before "hm = new HangmanController();" add "if (hm!=null) hm.stopwatch.stop();" or an appropriate method-call.

Comment: But this only deals with the one timer-problem. A better approach would be to write a method within your HangmanController that adjusts the speed/difficulty, instead of creating a new instance (imho).